# Открытие/закрытие экранной клавиатуры по нажатию на кнопку во Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, клавиатура

В проекте на Flutter необходимо реализовать открытие/закрытие экранной клавиатуры при нажатии на кнопку.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text('Заголовок'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.keyboard),
            onPressed: () {
              // При нажатии на эту кнопку открыть клавиатуру
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
```

Смотрел уже плагины [Flutter Keyboard Visibility](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_keyboard_visibility) и [keyboard_visibility](https://pub.dev/packages/keyboard_visibility), но они только уведомляют о смене состояния клавиатуры. Есть ли какие то плагины с данной реализацией? Либо каким образом можно это сделать самому?

Answer (score 2):

В `Flutter` все есть из коробки...

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  FocusNode _focusNode = FocusNode();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Заголовок'),
          actions: <Widget>[
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.keyboard),
              onPressed: () {
                if (_focusNode.hasFocus) {
                  FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
                } else {
                  FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(_focusNode);
                }
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
        body: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              TextFormField(
                focusNode: _focusNode,
                decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Field'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Объяснять не буду зачем и что, но фокус мне не подходит и нужна возможность скрытия и показа клавиатуры программным путем, когда на экране нет ничего, ни текстовых полей и т.д. Собственно по этому и задал вопрос =) С коробки я такой возможности не вижу)

Comment: @Leksor ну тогда пишите нативный плагин. Только смыла в этом я не вижу...

Comment: Если вкратце, нужна подобная реализация: должно быть выбрано текстовое поле, но при этом клавиатура не должна отображаться на экране. Ввод происходит с внешней клавиатуры. Однако если внешний клавиатуры нет - необходимо показать экранную клавиатуру для ввода. Использовал RawKeyboardListener и на эмуляторе все работало отлично, пока не подошло время для тестирования на реальных устройствах. Ни на одном реальном устройстве с использованием RawKeyboardListener к сожалению ничего не работает. Устройства не принимают ввод с внешней клавиатуры если конкретно не выбрано какое либо текстовое поле.

Comment: По этому было решено делать фокус на существующее текстовое поле для ввода данных с внешней клавиатуры. Однако в данном случае нужна возможность скрытия виртуальной клавиатуры пока активно поле для ввода и вызывать экранную клавиатуру только при необходимости при нажатии на клавишу на экране. Нашел много сообщений на англоязычных ресурсах, что RawKeyboardListener действительно не работает на реальных устройствах.

Answer (score 0):

С учётом комментариев к ответу https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1168434/481 :

Скрытие виртуальной клавиатуры при подключённой физической - это функция ОС android. Скорее всего можно сделать костыли, для решения проблемы, но лучше изменить опцию в настройках, которая по-умолчанию включена.

На Samsung это можно сделать изменением настройки:
Настройки - Общие настройки - Физическая клавиатура - Отображение экранной клавиатуры.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]